# Python program to serve the output of a command via HTTP

Tags: python

I wonder if anyone can help me web enhance a python script which runs a status command for various apps:

```
/app/app1/bin/status.sh
/app/app2/bin/status.sh
```

A check() function in the script creates a hash:

```
results = check_function()

results['app1']['status'] = 'running'
results['app2']['status'] = 'stopped'
```

My current solution is terminal only and a display_results() function prints the status of the environment  to the terminal with appropriate escape sequences to colorize it:

```
display_results(results)
```

I'd like to "web enable" the command so that it can have report the results dictionary over the web.

I'm thinking I can just have it listen on a socket and write HTML through a string template or would it be better to have BaseHTTPServer do the listening but how to get it to serve the output of a command rather than the index.html file on a filesystem?

This is not a production application it's used as a tool for developers to do a mass check on the status of an app.

The terminal version works with python 2.4 (Centos 5.8) but there's nothing to stop me from using python 2.7

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd use [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).

Comment: I've heard good stories about [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: I've got flask working with a similar command but for this one I've got to stick to python and the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing the whole code, why not use something like this:

```
import BaseHTTPServer

class MyHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write("<html><body>You accessed path: {}</body></html>".format(self.path))

BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 80), MyHTTPRequestHandler).serve_forever()
```

No problem adding code to `MyHTTPRequestHandler` that calls some script or whatever using `self.path` as argument and adding the result to the formatted page. Where is the problem with the batteries for such a simple task? Additionally the `subprocess` module might help, especially `subprocess.Popen(["echo", "test"]).communicate()`.

Comment: Hochl, thank you very much for that. Your little sample and explanation are excellent.